# Can I change "OK" button style in Select Dialog to emphasized?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

anyone know if sapui5 provide solution/function to change button style in select dialog? I've checked the SAPUI5 sdk but there is none for this solution.

Comment: What is your current UI5 version? If you're able to use the latest version, the issue should be solved automatically as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57256801/5846045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with using "private" properties then you can use **_oOkButton** property of SelectDialog or else you can use **_getOkButton** function which also is kind of "private" and returns ok button instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the instance of the Select Dialog and get all buttons using the following methods. Select Dialog is a dialog only, you can use the methods of `sap.m.Dialog`

Let say you have the instance of the dialog as `oSlectDialog` then

- `oSlectDialog.getButtons()` - will return all the Buttons in the footer. You can use loop them and give custom class accordingly.

  `var oBtns = oSlectDialog.getButtons()
  for(var b in oBtns) {
    var oBtn = oBtns[b];//You can check for button instance, if you want to add custom class differently.
    oBtn.addStyleClass("YourCustomClass"); 
  }`
- You can also use the `sap.m.Dialog` methods like `oSlectDialog.getBeginButton()`, `oSlectDialog.getEndButton()`.

Comment: This is not entirely correct (version 1.67.0). SelectDialog does not inherit from Dialog. However, internally it uses a Dialog. But you cannot access its (public) functions directly. Getting the internally used dialog through the private property "_dialog" of the SelectDialog would make the examples possible.

Answer (score 0):

[Since UI5 1.62.0](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/cb939392ab15479a201d6f40bd8483e572e6397a), the primary action <kbd>OK</kbd> (later renamed to <kbd>Select</kbd>) is automatically emphasized if the theme is `sap_fiori_3`.

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.SelectDialog/sample/sap.m.sample.SelectDialog

> [image: sap.m.SelectDialog]

If it's not urgent, I'd suggest to avoid relying on private methods/ properties, but update to the latest UI5 version and themes.

**Update:** and since 1.70 (`commit:1f421b0`), the button is automatically emphasized in other supported themes too, such as `sap_belize`, `sap_belize_plus`

---

<sup>Related Github issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2254</sup>